# How to use ng-repeat inside <td> tags without changing the table design

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have nested 3 lists. And I want those data to display in a table. When I'm trying like this,

```html
 <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat-start="item in searchResultList" >                    
                    <td>{{item.Group.AuditDate | date:"MM/dd/yyyy h:mma"}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.Group.User}}</td> 
                    
                </tr>  
                <tr ng-repeat-start="x in item.DeviceList.DescriptionList">
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>   
                    <td>{{x.Description}}</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="y in x.ChangesList">
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td> 
                    <td>{{y.ChangeFrom}}</td>
                    <td>{{y.ChangeTo}}</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>           
            </tbody>
```

Then It displays like this. [image]

But I don't want to repeat lines when each data repeat. I want to display all the 1st data in a straight line,and when description repeat for the same date and user, then it should be in a new line. I want an alignment like this.
[image]

Comment: The question needs to be more clear. Add a proper code snippet. Then we can help. :)

Comment: try using ng-template when you are using ng-repeat data to get populate in td tags

Comment: Can u explain bit more?

Comment: the simplest and more readable way is to create a new object in the way you want to display in UI. You can write all complex calculation and data formatting in javascript/controller and then just use ng-repeat in UI to display them.

Comment: @RICKYKUMAR - I did the data formatting in Controller. But when binding ng-repeat repeats the rows.That's why it displays like 1st image. But I want to display like 2nd one.

Comment: parse your data in below format in the controller and then use ng-repeat to display. `[{'08/11/2016 5:56PM', 'Administrator','Aaa','b','c'}, {'', '','','d','f'},{'','','Bbb','b','c'},{'10/16/2015 11:41AM','Tharuka','Ccc','c','d'}]`

Comment: Please also add your JSON object over which you are iterating. @TKrish

Comment: It worked @RICKYKUMAR. Thanks. And that's easy. And it cannot be done in the view. Because of the repetition of the rows when using ng-repeat.

Comment: @TKrish Just added the same to Answer, request you to mark it as answer so that others can get benefit

Comment: Looks like you need a couple of templates and a test to see if it's the first data row in the set, if so display the first item in current row.

Answer (score 1):

Parse your data in below format in the controller and then use ng-repeat to display.

`[{'08/11/2016 5:56PM', 'Administrator','Aaa','b','c'}, {'', '','','d','f'},{'','','Bbb','b','c'},{'10/16/2015 11:41AM','Tharuka','Ccc','c','d'}]`